# prove that using uniform bounded theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

> Let $y=(\eta_j),\eta_j\in \mathbb C$, be such that $\sum \xi_j\eta_j$ converges for every $x=(\xi_j)\in c_0$ where $c_0\subset l^\infty$ is the subspace of all complex sequences converging to zero. Show that $\sum |\eta_j| < \infty$

using theorem ( Let (Tn) be a sequence of bounded linear operators Tn:X->Y from a Banach space X into a normed space Y such that ‖T(n)x‖ is bounded for every  x∈X,say ,Absolutely (T(n)x) less than or equal cx, where cx is real number. Then the sequence of the norms ‖T(n)‖is bounded that is , there is a c such that Absolutely (T(n)) less than or equal c)

This question in book Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications page 255 question (10)

Comment: please edit your question to be readable. Put a $before and after math symbols.

Comment: Kalil, I had to fetch the book to copy the problem. This is not normal. For your future questions, you should either learn Tex formatting, or at least post a photography of your problem.

Comment: Have you an idea what operators you could pick for $T_n$?

Comment: See also [this recent thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794798/show-that-the-element-in-ell1/796397#796397).

Answer (score 3):

First, we assume that $\eta_j$ are real numbers. Define for an integer $n$ and $a\in c_0$, $$T_n(a):=\sum_{j=1}^n\eta_ja_j.$$
Then $T_n$ is a bounded linear functional on $c_0$. Taking for $j\leqslant n$, $a_j=\operatorname{sgn}(a_j)$ and $a_j=0$ if $j\gt n$, we can see that $\lVert T_n\rVert=\sum_{j=1}^n|\eta_j|$. The wanted conclusion follows from the uniform boundedness principle.

In the general case, write $\eta_j=b_j+ib'_j$, where $b_j$ and $b'_j$ are real numbers and use the previous reasoning with $(b_j)_{j\geqslant 1}$ and $(b'_j)_{j\geqslant 1}$.

Comment: Note that the $\eta_j$ are complex numbers.

Comment: @G.T.R I missed that. Fixed now.